# getElementById with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

I have an interating function that assigns id's. i.e. like

`$('#mycooldiv' + idNumber).text();`

I'm wondering how I can take this - `'#mycooldiv' + idNumber` and use it within a

`var div = document.getElementById('#mycooldiv' + idNumber);` - because the later doesn't work ?

I have also tried

```
var elem = $('#mycooldiv' + idNumber);
var div = document.getElementById(elem);
```

and that fails as well ?

Comment: if you are using jquery what is the purpose of using document.getElementById. `var elem = $('#mycooldiv' + idNumber);` and `var div = document.getElementById('mycooldiv' + idNumber);` both are same

Comment: No - they are not. Because some cross-browser code is better placed NOT using jQuery. Why do you always revert to a jQuery solution ? Sometimes a jQuery solution is not always the best - hence the reason for the question.

Comment: i mean if you are using jQuery, dont try to use both. i already mention both ways to do this task in my previous comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementById` just need the id, the `#` is not needed.

`var div = document.getElementById('mycooldiv' + idNumber);`

Comment: please tell me that's not the case. ok, i'm shocked with *embarrasment* :)

Comment: That _is_ the case, sorry. jQuery selectors are based on CSS selectors, so `#` prefix means id, `.` prefix means class, and no prefix means element tag name (to name just the three simplest options).

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = $('#mycooldiv' + idNumber);
var div = elem[0];
```

though of course that's less efficient than calling `getElementById` directly, and loses the advantage of jQuery selectors that there is no error when the element does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

you're really close to the solution. IN jquery the notation $() gives you your element, so in your case this would work:

```
var div = $('#mycooldiv'+idNumber);
```

This IS your desired element.

EDIT: If you insist on using document.getElementById you should write:

```
var div = document.getElementById('mycoodiv'+idNumber);
```

the #-notation is only used with jquery and denotes an id in css-syntax wich jQuery uses (and which is far more powerful and versatile than document.getElementById).

Comment: hi - thanks for the response but that's not what I'm looking for.